# Failed edit to a question says: "Your answer couldn't be submitted"

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I was adding relevant tags to a question. But the number of tags exceeded  5 and the system gave me this error:

> Your **answer** couldn't be submitted

While I was editing a **question**.

> [image]

Comment: Without freehand red circles, I can't pick out what you think is wrong... oh, I can. Also, "....beacuse: Please..." doesn't work in English.

Comment: @BillWoodger what is not clear to you? have you read post attentively?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I think the first sentence was meant to be a joke: [freehand red circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/220428).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy well I couldn't judged it as joke..:D

Comment: @BillWoodger: Maybe he _did_ use a freehand red circle, but he happened to choose the same red color as the background. As an experienced Meta user, you should be so good at spotting them that you can see one even when it's the same color as the background.

Answer (score -26):

The cause seems clear to me : *Please enter no more than 5 tags*. No question on SO can have more than 5 tags. The error is not due to a bug, at most you could propose a feature-request to allow more than 5 tags but I do not think it would be accepted.

*New tags cannot be created from the mobile site. The tag 'vnext' is new'*. Here again it is not a bug, because the application advertises it cannot do it. But it would have more chances to be accepted as a feature request, because prioritization of developpements is the main reason for a mobile site to have less feature than the normal one.

Summary : you tried to add a 6th tag and the system refused that : it is perfectly normal

Comment: The question is not "why did I get an error," but "why does it say *an **answer** couldn't be submitted* when I was editing a **question**."